# How do I remove a UITableView row while deleting its data from Core Data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am deleting a row from a UITableView that receives its information from CoreData. Currently, I have it figured out to where it can remove the CoreData info, but it's not wiping out the row in the UITableView. Most methods I've employed have resulted in crashes. Here is the raw code (credit: blog.revivalx.com)

```
var peopleArray: NSMutableArray = [People]() //People is CoreData entity

@IBOutlet weak var contactTable: UITableView!

let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
            let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
            context.deleteObject(peopleArray[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)
            peopleArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            context.save(nil)
```

I've tried inserting:

```
contactTable.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath.row
], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

into this code and have been met with errors. A plethora of sources have not turned up an answer for me on how to perform both removals simultaneously.

How do I remove the row from the UITableView and it's corresponding entry in CoreData at the same time in Swift?

Thanks

Edit:

Here is the function in its entirety:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

    let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    context.deleteObject(peopleArray[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
    peopleArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

    contactTable.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    context.save(nil)
    contactTable.reloadData()
}
}
```

Comment: What is `myList`?  How does it relate to `peopleArray`?  Which of these is used in `numberOfRowsInSection` and/or `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
contactTable.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath.row], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

should be change to this method due to the fact that it supposed to get `an array of indexPath` not `array indexPath.row`

```
contactTable.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

Comment: Thanks. It's an improvement, but they still seem to be working out of sync. When I use the above line before deleting the CoreData, I get 'invalid number of rows in section 0'.. and a massive wall of text I can print out here if that helps. When I use it after, I get 'array index out of range'.

Comment: what do you mean ? and don't forget to  use `reloadData()`

Comment: Comment updated - I hit enter on accident. Using reloadData() doesn't have an affect on the current issues though I've inserted it at the end of the func.

Comment: where are you calling this line?  is it in the `commitEditingStyle` method

Comment: Added the function in its entirety to the original question including reloadData()

Answer (score 0):

You are doing too much. This should (roughly) work according to the MVC (Model View Controller) design pattern:

- Core Data takes care of the data, that is, the model.
- UITableView is responsible for displaying the data.
- Your code is the controller which reacts to user actions and tells the model what to do.

The user taps on delete, you tell Core Data to delete the object and the view to reload the data.

So you should remove `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` from your delegate function. Telling the table view to `reloadData` should result in `UITableView` calling your data source delegate functions like `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`. In that function you ask Core Data for the right data and hand it over to the view.

Or better yet create a new Master-Detail Application with Swift and Core Data options and you get all the correct source code for free. This code handles it differently from what I suggested above: It tells the table view to `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`, but it doesn't do both, either.